# filepicker.io: is user or group permissions / authentication possible?

Tags: javascript, authentication, permissions, filepicker.io

I have a  meteor.js application in which I have integrated filepicker.io to do file uploads. It works all fine and dandy but now I am refactoring my app to be multi-tenant.

There are different groups of tenants that in theory would be using filepicker to upload/retrieve files that only that specific group should have access to.

- Is this even possible with filepicker.io?
- If it is how would I go about implementing the per group authentication and permissioning?

Comment: Permissions should be handled on the server side.